# MySQL INSERT on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table user_has_alerts (userID, alertID, dateAlerted) and i'm trying to update all NULL values in dateAlerted field for a given user to the current date.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nope, it's part of a team project at uni that we've been doing for the past 8 months :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE user_has_alerts SET dateAlerted = CURDATE() 
 WHERE userID = X AND dateAlerted IS NULL
```

Comment: Ah, for some odd reason i thought it would be an INSERT INTO.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `user_has_alerts` SET `dateAlerted` = NOW() WHERE `dateAlerted` IS NULL AND userID = 1
```